# Eigen floating-point precision

Tags: c++, r, matrix, precision, eigen

I am having trouble with floating-point precision by using `Eigen`.

I have two `Eigen::MatrixXd`; the first matrix `A` (nx1) contains only positive integers numbers, while the second matrix `B` (nx1) contains a single column filled with the same real number (ex: -0.714312).

I need to compute the following `Eigen::MatrixXd`:

```
const auto exponential = [](double x)
{ return std::exp(x); };


MatrixXd W = B.unaryExpr(exponential);
MatrixXd residuals = A - W;
```

The problem is that when I print the sum of the residuals:

```
cout << residuals.sum();
// output = 6.16951e-06
```

I get a different value that by performing the same operation using R and the same input matrices.

By using R matrices I get `-2.950208e-09`. While the sum of the elements of `A`, `B` and `W` are the same both in `C++` and in `R`.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that R is using the x87 FPU with extended precision (80bits) whereas Eigen is using SSE units (64bits/double). You can check that by using `Matrix<long double,Dynamic,Dynamic>` matrix types or by making sure that your compiler will target the x87 FPU units.

Comment: Unfortunately using long double gives the same result. How can I check that my compiler targets the x87 FPU units?

Comment: Then please be more specific with actual values for A and B so that we can reproduce.