# QR factorization in R not giving correct answer with large sparse matrix

Tags: r, numerical-methods, qr-decomposition

I have a sparse matrix of type `dgTMatrix` built with the Matrix package in R and I'm trying to solve for the vector `x` in `Ax=b` using QR decomposition, but it is not working correctly.

For example below I am solving for a random `A, b` and you can see the method works with the norm of `Ax-b = 0`

```
A <- matrix(rnorm(9),ncol=3)
decomp <- qr(A)
b <- rnorm(3)
x <- qr.coef(decomp,b)
(A %*% x - b) %>% norm
[1] 3.885781e-16
```

My `A` and `b` are like this:

````
A: 173700 x 173700 sparse Matrix of class "dgTMatrix"``` 
b: 173700 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"```
````

When I take a QR decomposition of `A` I get the following:

```
qr_decomp <- qr(A, LAPACK = TRUE, tol = 1e-10)
qr_decomp
'MatrixFactorization' of Formal class 'sparseQR' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  ..@ V   :Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  .. .. ..@ i       : int [1:13350377] 0 173283 173284 173285 173286 1 2 3 2 3 ...
  .. .. ..@ p       : int [1:173701] 0 5 8 11 19 22 25 30 33 36 ...
  .. .. ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 173700 173700
  .. .. ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..@ x       : num [1:13350377] -9.27e+01 2.35e-03 -1.28e+02 2.35e-03 6.40e+01 ...
  .. .. ..@ factors : list()
  ..@ beta: num [1:173700] 6.88e-05 7.80e-14 1.24e-06 3.88e-05 7.80e-14 ...
  ..@ p   : int [1:173700] 34977 38066 38838 39610 38067 38839 34980 38069 38841 39613 ...
  ..@ R   :Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  .. .. ..@ i       : int [1:24075359] 0 1 1 2 0 1 2 3 4 4 ...
  .. .. ..@ p       : int [1:173701] 0 1 2 4 8 9 11 12 13 15 ...
  .. .. ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 173700 173700
  .. .. ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..@ x       : num [1:24075359] 1.57e+02 3.58e+06 -1.26e+03 3.58e+06 1.92e-03 ...
  .. .. ..@ factors : list()
  ..@ q   : int [1:173700] 35749 38838 38066 36522 38839 38067 35752 38841 38069 36525 ...
  ..@ Dim : int [1:2] 173700 173700
```

According to the [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/sparseQR-class.html) for `sparseQR` class,

> For a sparse m×n (“long”: m≥n) rectangular matrix A, the sparse QR decomposition is either
> of the form PA=QR with a (row) permutation matrix P, (encoded in the p slot of the result) if the q slot is of length 0,
> or of the form PAP∗=QR with an extra (column) permutation matrix P∗ (encoded in the q slot).

Since `qr_decomp@q` exists, per the docs, this must be of the form `PAP∗=QR`

Anyway, the same procedure as above is not working in this case:

```
decomp <- qr(A)
x <- qr.coef(decomp, b)
(A %*% x - b) %>% norm
[1] 3.540814e+24
```

The above value is really far from zero.

Inspecting matrix A everything looks okay to me:

```
!(A@x %>% is.finite) %>% any
[1] FALSE
!(b@x %>% is.finite) %>% any
[1] FALSE

> A[1:10, 1:10]
10 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dgTMatrix"
                                                                                                                                                 
 [1,] -5.366088e+08  5.301600e-02  .             .             .             .             .             .             .             .           
 [2,]  4.418000e-02 -5.366088e+08  4.418000e-02  .             .             .             .             .             .             .           
 [3,]  .             4.123467e-02 -5.366088e+08  4.123467e-02  .             .             .             .             .             .           
 [4,]  .             .             3.976200e-02 -5.366088e+08  3.976200e-02  .             .             .             .             .           
 [5,]  .             .             .             3.887840e-02 -5.366088e+08  3.887840e-02  .             .             .             .           
 [6,]  .             .             .             .             3.828933e-02 -5.366088e+08  3.828933e-02  .             .             .           
 [7,]  .             .             .             .             .             3.786857e-02 -5.366088e+08  3.786857e-02  .             .           
 [8,]  .             .             .             .             .             .             2.650800e-02 -5.366088e+08  1.251767e-02  .           
 [9,]  .             .             .             .             .             .             .             9.719600e-03 -5.366088e+08  9.719600e-03
[10,]  .             .             .             .             .             .             .             .             9.572333e-03 -5.366088e+08
```

However, there are large values present in the matrices:

```
max(b)
[1] 3.978441e+22
max(A)
[1] 3.979517e+22
min(b)
[1] 0
min(A)
[1] -7.958754e+22
```

Could it be the large values messing things up with some kind of round off error? Or am I missing some key info about QR not converging in some case?

Comment: Not totally sure, but this may be caused by R's finite precision arithmetic. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45844406/precision-of-matrix-calculation-r-vs-stata) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33813678/eigen-floating-point-precision). Your very large / very small numbers in `A` may be causing the difference, unobservable in your `rnorm(9)` example.

Comment: I can't come up with a reproducible error.  You might look at the condition number of your matrix (`?rcond`).  If I try for a big enough matrix I get a segfault ... https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=6794&group_id=61&atid=294

Comment: ```rcond``` gave me an error saying matrix was too big but ```condest(A)``` returned ```4.760301e+48```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** it does appear that large values will lead to problems; scaling the inputs appears to help.

An example that *isn't* problematic, even though I used Cauchy-distributed samples to fill in the matrix (which leads to a wide range of values):

```r
set.seed(101)
library(Matrix)
## d <- 173700
d <- 1e3
## n <- 1e6
n <- 1e5
randfun <- rcauchy
As <- sparseMatrix(i=integer(0),
                   j=integer(0),
                   dims = c(d, d), repr = "T")
As[cbind(sample(d, size = n, replace = TRUE),
         sample(d, size = n, replace = TRUE))] <- randfun(n)
bs <- sparseMatrix(i = 1:d, j = rep(1, d), x = randfun(d))
qr_decomp <- qr(As, LAPACK = TRUE, tol = 1e-10)

decomp <- qr(As)
xs <- qr.coef(decomp, bs)
(As %*% xs - bs) |> norm()  ## 1.19e-09
```

If I use larger values for `d` (matrix/vector dimensions) and `n` (number of non-zero elements), either the computation takes a long time or I get a [segmentation fault](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=6794&group_id=61&atid=294).

However, if I set `randfun <- function(n) rcauchy(n, scale = 1e20)` in the example above I do get large deviations.

Scaling the inputs seems to solve the problem, although I don't know if it will work for what you want to do ...

```r
As2 <- As/1e20
bs2 <- bs/1e20
decomp2 <- qr(As2)
xs2 <- qr.coef(decomp2, bs2)
(As2 %*% xs2 - bs2) |> norm()
```

Comment: Re your problematic example in Issues: How long was it running before the segfault? It's been running several minutes now (with no output) and no error on my Ubuntu box. Update. It appeared to crash Rstudio rather than R. In a Terminal launched session the segfault was immediate: `*** caught segfault *** address 0x563fa5326fd8, cause 'memory not mapped'`

Comment: Mine segfaulted almost immediately (in the terminal, didn't try anything else).

Comment: Yeah. I think Rstudio was just holding on, trying to fix, whatever it got from R before it, too, crashed.

Comment: Thanks, When you say large deviations what do you mean by that? I see your example had a norm of 1.19e-09 which is fairly close to zero. Did you ever reproduce a large number with that norm?

Comment: I got a large number for `norm(As %*% xs - bs)`  when I set `randfun <- function(n) rcauchy(n, scale = 1e20)` and re-ran the simulation code (i.e., replace the line that says `randfun <- rcauchy`)